# How to show the canonical homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings with  identity and $f:A\to B$ an injective homomorphism of rings. For any prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ of $B$, denote $f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ by $\mathfrak p$, how to show the canonical homomorphism $A_{\mathfrak p}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$ is injective?

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that might follow from the universal property. Did you try using that?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Yes, I factor it as $A_{\mathfrak p}\to B_{\mathfrak p}\to B_{\mathfrak q}$, the first is injective, but I wonder if the second is injective.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I wonder if jgon's answer is correct. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997043/do-we-also-have-to-use-the-condition-that-f-is-an-immersion

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424884/possible-mistake-in-exercise-in-hartshorne-exercise-ii-2-18b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, let $k$ be a field, let $A=k[x]$ and $B=k[x,y]/(xy)$, and let $f:A\to B$ be the obvious inclusion.  Then the ideal $\mathfrak{q}=xB\subset B$ is prime, and the induced map $A_{f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})}\to B_\mathfrak{q}$ is not injective: $x$ is nonzero in $A_{f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})}$ but is $0$ in $B_\mathfrak{q}$ since $xy=0$ and $y\not\in\mathfrak{q}$.

Comment: Nice! I was typing this exact example, but you beat me to it.

Comment: I wonder if jgon's answer is correct, please help me check it, thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997043/do-we-also-have-to-use-the-condition-that-f-is-an-immersion