# Injectivity of map on sheaves $f^\sharp : \mathcal{O}_X \to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. Hartshorne $2.18$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi : A \to B$ be a homomorphism of rings, and let $f: Y = \operatorname{Spec} B \to X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ be the induced morphism of affine schemes. Show that $\varphi$ is injective if and only if the map of sheaves $f^\sharp : \mathcal{O}_X \to f_* \mathcal{O}_Y$ is injective.

---

Been having trouble with this for a while now. It is a problem from the book of Hartshorne.

If we start with assuming $\varphi$ to be injective, then in order to show that the map on sheaves is injective it is satisfactory to prove that the map on stalks $$f^\sharp_\mathfrak{p} : \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A, f(\mathfrak{p})} \to \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B, \mathfrak{p}} $$ is injective for $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} B$.

Now few remarks here. I've noticed that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}A, f(\mathfrak{p})} = A_{f(\mathfrak{p})}$ and that $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}B, \mathfrak{p}}  = B_\mathfrak{p}$ . We also have that $f(\mathfrak{p})=\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ so in essence we are trying to show that $$A_{\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})} \to B_\mathfrak{p}$$ is injective given that $\varphi$ is.

The issue comes here since apparently this is not true. Here is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997819/how-to-show-the-canonical-homomorphism-a-mathfrak-p-to-b-mathfrak-q-is-i?noredirect=1&lq=1) to a thread here which shows that there is a counterexample. It's likely that I'm doing something wrong here, but I cannot figure out what so any help is welcome.

Comment: You're making a misconception that the stalks of $(f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)$ coincide with the stalks of $\mathcal{O}_Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you are thinking that the stalks of $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ coincide with the stalks of $\mathcal{O}_Y$. This is cleary not true in general since direct image functor is not exact unless you assume that $Y \longrightarrow X$ is an immersion.

Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be an arbitrary point, of courser we shall check that the corresponding morphism
$$A_{\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$
The problem is to compute the RHS. It can be done as follows.
$$(f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}} = \operatorname{colim}_{\mathfrak{p} \in U} \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(U)) = \operatorname{colim}_{\mathfrak{p} \in D(g)} \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(D(g))) = (A \setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1}B,$$
where $(A\setminus \mathfrak{p})$ is viewed as a multiplicative set in $B$ via $\varphi$. To clarify this computation:

- The first equality follows from definition.
- The second equality follows from the fact that distinguished open sets form a basis of Zariski topology.
- The last one is a consequence of the fact that $f^{-1}(D(g))= D(\varphi(g))$ (can you prove this?)

By an abuse of notation, we can assume that $A \subset B$ since $\varphi$ is injective. So we have reduced the question to proving the canonical morphism
$$A_{\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow (A\setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1}B \ \ \ \ \frac{a}{s} \longmapsto \frac{a}{s}$$
is injective. This should be obvious.

Since you seem to be confused about stalks. I would say that the stalks we are taking, i.e.
$$\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}}$$
is completely different from the ones
$$\mathcal{O}_{X,f(\mathfrak{q})} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,\mathfrak{q}}$$
coming from the definition of a morphism of locally ringed spaces (for which we require them to be local maps). The first one is obtained by taking stalks of two sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ which are both sheaves on $X$ so you can only speak about stalks of points of $X$. Another point is that the morphisms $\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ exist beforehand at the level of sheaves while $\mathcal{O}_{X,f(\mathfrak{q})} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,\mathfrak{q}}$ do not come from a morphism of sheaves.

In fact, the second one is obtained from the first one by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\mathcal{O}_{X,f(\mathfrak{q})} = \operatorname{colim}_{f(\mathfrak{q}) \in U} \mathcal{O}_X(U) = & \longrightarrow \operatorname{colim}_{\mathfrak{q} \in f^{-1}(U)} \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(U)) = (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(\mathfrak{q})}  \\ & \longrightarrow \operatorname{colim}_{\mathfrak{q} \in V}\mathcal{O}_Y(V) = \mathcal{O}_{Y,\mathfrak{q}}.\end{split} \end{equation}
You can see that the second morphism is obtained by the universal property of colimits, or I can say that the indexing sets are different, one varies over open subsets of form $f^{-1}(U)$ and one varies over all open subsets.

Comment: Could you clarify $\operatorname{colim}_{\mathfrak{p} \in D(g)} \mathcal{O}_Y(f^{-1}(D(g))) = (A \setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1}B$? @alexey-do

Comment: Also it's a bit confusing still how do you get $A_{\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ when this should actually be $$A_{f(\mathfrak{p})} \longrightarrow (f_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ for $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} B$. @alexey-do

Comment: @Laura I edited my answer for your first comment, for the second one you can rethink.

Comment: In Hartshorne for a map $f: X \to Y$ he defines the induced map on stalks of the sheaf map $f^\sharp : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ as $$f^\sharp_x :  \mathcal{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to  \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$$ for $x \in X$. In our case we have a map $Y \to X$ so shouldn't $\mathfrak{p}$ be in $Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$? @alexey-do

Comment: @Laura I added a lot, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The sheaf $f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} B}$ is not the same as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} B}$; these sheaves lie on different spaces. So there is some subtlety to taking a stalk of $f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} B}$: given a point $P \in \mathrm{Spec} A$ corresponding to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, the stalk of $f_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} B}$ at $P$ is the ring $S^{-1}B$, where $S = \varphi(A \setminus \mathfrak{p}) \subset B$.

This is not localization at a prime of $B$! What you are really doing is *treating $B$ as an $A$-module*, and then localizing that $A$-module at a prime of $A$. The injectivity statement you want then follows from standard facts about localizing *modules,* rather than localizing two rings at different prime ideals.

Comment: This makes sense and avoids the identification of the image of $\varphi$ with a subset of $B$, but still it seems that you are taking $P \in \operatorname{Spec} A$ instead of $P \in \mathrm{Spec} B$ which I think we should do? @cj-dowd

Comment: @Laura The reason for this is that the sheaf $f_*\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is a sheaf on the space $X$, so it is reasonable that localizing at a point in $X = \mathrm{Spec} A$ is related to the corresponding prime ideal of $A$. Alexey's answer explains why localizing by $\varphi(A \setminus \mathfrak{p})$ is the correct way of taking the stalk by using the definition of the stalk explicitly.

Comment: I think we have $f_*\mathcal{O}_{Y}(U) = \mathcal{O}_{Y}(f^{-1}(U))$ so what do you mean by sheaf on $X$? I have not seen this type of consideration anywhere in Hartshorne where we look at the stalk map $f^\sharp_x :  \mathcal{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to  \mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ for a point in the target of $f$. @cj-dowd